# Calculating slope and intercept with interaction terms in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

How can you solve the following in R?

LOG_D = a+b1*PROD_QTY+b2*DIRECT_D+b3*CHILD_D+b4*PROD_QTY*DIRECT_D

LOG_D = Log(DURATION *Total time spent at a site in minutes*)

PROD_QTY = Quantity of the product purchase by the household

DIRECT_D = A dummy variable indicating whether the transaction is incurred directly from a hotel website (1) or other third-party travel website (0)

CHILD_D = A dummy variable indicating whether the household has any children

I need to find the impact of PROD_QTY on LOG_DURATION. Calculate the intercept and the slope for transactions incurred 1) directly from a hotel website and 2) other third-party travel website, respectively

Answer (score 0):

More simply, what you have is $Y = B_0 + B_1 X_1 + B_2 X_2 + B_3 X_3 + B_4 X_1 X_2$. Get your estimates for $B_0$, $B_1$, $B_2$, and $B_4$ ($B_3$ is irrelevant to this problem). Simply plug in $0$ and $1$ for $X_2$ and move around some terms to evaluate. When $X_2 = 1$, your equation looks like

```
$$Y = B_0 + B_1 X_1 + B_2 * 1 + B_3 X_3 + B_4 X_1 *1
= B_0 + B_1 X_1 + B_2 + B_3 X_3 + B_4 X_1 
= (B_0 + B_2) + (B_1 + B_4) X_1 + B_3 X_3 $$
```

Now, your slope and intercept for $X_1$ are $(B_1 + B_4)$ and $(B_0 + B_2)$ respectively. You can do the same with $X_2 = 0$.

[Note: I can't figure out how to make LeTeX work here...]